# Dynamics not updating normally in Wolfram Cloud

Tags: dynamic, wolfram-cloud

In *Mathematica*, `InputFields` and `Sliders` that are connected to `Dynamic`s will change their values if the variable they control is changed procedurally.  In Wolfram Cloud, only the first `Dynamic` in a notebook seems to behave this way.  In this example,

```
Grid@{{"a =", InputField[Dynamic[a], Number], 
   Slider[Dynamic[a], {0, 1}]}, {"b =", 
   InputField[Dynamic[b], Number], Slider[Dynamic[b], {0, 1}]}}

a = 0.25;
b = 0.75;
Print["a = ", a, " b = ", b];
```

The `InputField`s and `Slider`s interact properly.  But if I then execute this:

```
a = 0.75;
b = 0.25;
Print["a = ", a, " b = ", b];
```

The `InputField` and `Slider` associated with variable `a` update to the new value, but the ones for `b` do not.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?  I'm trying to set up a user interface that consists of `InputField`s that can be changed interactively, but that can also be set to a number of known value sets procedurally. It works as desired in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Try `Print["a = ", Dynamic@a, " b = ", Dynamic@b];`